# Laravel Passport multple session auth guard

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-10, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

during laravel passport redirect for authorization (/oauth/authorize), can I specify to passport which auth guard to check authentication for (if I want auth for admin which is not the default), instead of using the guard specified in the passport.php config?